# N-Dimensional Cartesian Product of a set in Julia

Tags: iterator, julia, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I would like to see if there is a more elegant/eficient/julian way to produce a function that takes an iterable and a integer and returns the Cartesian or exterior product of the iterable with itself the specified number of times. 
In my opinion, the desirable way would be to produce an array of arrays, or a tuple of arrays, or a set of arrays, but if that is not the proper way to do it then I would like to understand why. I have come with the following function, which, to my eyes, looks overly "high-level". This is what I made:

```
using Base.Iterators

function ncartprod(ss, n)
   argumento=fill(ss, n)
   result=collect(product(argumento...))
   return(result)
end
```

The function returns an object with a strange type: a n-dimensional array of n-sized tuples... It makes sense for locating the elements,... but then, I could then simply produce one by one.

My original sets, here named ss, are simply arrays of integers, like this:

```
ss=[-1,0,1]
```

So I can make such things:

```
r=ncartprod(ss, 3)
```

and obtain something like this:

```
3×3×3 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 (-1, -1, -1)  (-1, 0, -1)  (-1, 1, -1)
 (0, -1, -1)   (0, 0, -1)   (0, 1, -1) 
 (1, -1, -1)   (1, 0, -1)   (1, 1, -1) 

[:, :, 2] =
 (-1, -1, 0)  (-1, 0, 0)  (-1, 1, 0)
 (0, -1, 0)   (0, 0, 0)   (0, 1, 0) 
 (1, -1, 0)   (1, 0, 0)   (1, 1, 0) 

[:, :, 3] =
 (-1, -1, 1)  (-1, 0, 1)  (-1, 1, 1)
 (0, -1, 1)   (0, 0, 1)   (0, 1, 1) 
 (1, -1, 1)   (1, 0, 1)   (1, 1, 1)
```

Is there a nicer, more efficient way?

Comment: What is exactly wrong  or not good enough with the result? That it is n-dimensional? You can get a vector of tuples with `vec(result)` without copying result data. If you want a set then you can use `Set` constructor on the result. Could you elaborate on your expectation of the result? Perhaps give an example?

Comment: I feel that the combination of "fill, then splat, then calculate, then collect" are to many steps for something that should be more direct, but maybe I am still not getting the Julian way of dealing with these things...  Ok. I know what botters me. If I try to make a relative "not small" cartesian product, say, n=12, the result is a 12-dimensional tensor. It is a bit more than unwielldy and actually it is quite memory expensive, I guess, against a list. Am I wrong?

Comment: Aside from a tiny amount of memory for the array header, it's the same amount of memory as a list. Why is this unwieldy? Finally, here's a one-liner:  `result = Iterators.product(ntuple(i->ss, n)...)`.

Answer (score 2):

tholy's comment should actually be the answer, and I actually have learned a few things by using the comments and trying to implement my own version. So, here is @tholy's comment answer and some things I found allong the way:

```
result(ss, n) = Iterators.product(ntuple(i->ss, n)...)
```

It is amazingly fast, and as the product is not collected, it the output object is very little in memory. The approaches that I was using were amazingly unwielldy in RAM cost. 
It seems that the iterator class in Julia is really eficient, and I should not try to list everything, but to call the pieces I need when I need them.

Comment: Could you explain what the 3 dots after `ntuple()` do/stand for?

Comment: @LuisChavesRodriguez they spread the arguments, product receives many arguments, i.e.  `product(a,b,c)` will yield the cartesian product between `a`, `b` and `c`. But `ntuple` returns a tuple, i,e, `(a,b,c)`. Therefore if we don't have the `...`, then `product((a,b,c))` would be called, which is not what we want. Instead `product((a,b,c)...) = product(a,b,c)`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a small improvement over the current answer: instead of using
`ntuple(i->ss, n)`, it might be more efficient to use `repeat([ss], n)`. Some testing I did on my laptop:

```
julia> a(val, n) = repeat([val], n)
a (generic function with 1 method)

julia> b(val, n) = ntuple(i -> val, n)
b (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time a(1:5, 10000);
  0.000172 seconds (3 allocations: 156.375 KiB)

julia> @time b(1:5, 10000);
  0.000985 seconds (10.00 k allocations: 703.359 KiB)
```

I agree though that the biggest improvement will come from the fact that `Iterators.product()` does not collect the product.